# Subtract and Add timestamps jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, timestamp

I know there is alot of things like this in stackoverflow but I can't seem to find something similar to mine.

I have datatable which has columns `start_timestamp` and `end_timestamp` and `total_hours` . I am using this in a task management to calculate how much time you spend in a task. So basically to get the `total_hours` in a task you need to subtract `end_timestamp` and `start_timestamp` but I am only able to get the hours. My timestamp format is like `Y-m-d h:i:s` 2016-05-04 23:00:00. Problem is I also need to get the minutes. Plus in the end I need to add all the hours for all the tasks. My current code is:

```
var totalhours = 0;
$.each(myObj[0], function(key,value) {

    var date_start = new Date(value.start_timestamp);
    var date_end = new Date(value.end_timestamp);
    var milisec = Math.abs(date_end - date_start);
    var seconds = milisec / 1000;
    var hours = parseInt( seconds / 3600 );

    totalhours += hours;

    var isdaily = '';
    if(value.is_daily == 0)
    {
        isdaily = 'Added'
    }
    else
    {
        isdaily = 'Daily'
    }

    t.row.add( [
        value.id,
        value.task_description,
        value.start_timestamp,
        value.end_timestamp,
        hours,
        value.name,
        value.assign,
        value.created_at,
        isdaily,
        value.status
    ] ).draw();
});
```

So basically `totalhours` is total hours for all the tasks and `hours` the hours per task, how I also include the minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem is I also need to get the minutes.

You need to add

```
var minutes = parseInt( seconds / 60 );
```

to

```
var hours = parseInt( seconds / 3600 );
```

Rest of the function logic needs to be manipulated accordingly.

If you want to convert 2.5 to 2 hours 30 minutes

```
var x = 2.5;
var hours = parseInt(x);
var minutes = ( x - parseInt(x) ) * 60;
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help. I knew about this but this formula will only get the minutes conversion in hours right? so if I have 2016-05-04 03:00:00 - 2016-05-04 01:00:00. That is 2 hours or 120 minutes right? What I need is if something like 2016-05-04 03:30:00 - 2016-05-04 01:00:00 then it will be 2 hours and 30 mins something similar.

Comment: You need to use `parseFloat(seconds / 3600 )` and then convert this in terms of minutes

Comment: @jackhammer013 I have added the example of converting a floating point hour value to hours-minutes. Please have a look.